# setTitleEdgeInsets for MacOS application

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsbutton, titleedgeinsets

I am building and application for MacOS where I would like to have distance between NSButton border and content.
Looking how I could do that I have seen there is function called **setTitleEdgeInsets** but it looks like it is only available for UIButton.
Is there alternative for NSButton? If not how could I achieve that?

Thanks and regards

Comment: I am also searching for this. If you found solution let me know.